# can't resolve a promise of a readstream ('csv-parser')

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse data from a .csv file, and save it to an array for later use.
I understand the concept of promises, but I have no idea what am I missing in my code that I cannot resolve the Promise and get the value (the string in the .csv file). It  while I can view all the data inside the promise (.on('data')) from debugging mode, I just can't save it in order to use it later in my 'try&catch'.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const { resolve } = require("path");

async function readCSV(filepath) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await fs
      .createReadStream(filepath)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", (data) => {
        results.push(data);
      })
      .on("error", (error) => reject(results))
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve(results);
      });
  });
}


const results = [];
const csvFilePath =
  "/languages.csv";

try {
  const languages = readCSV(csvFilePath).then((res) => {
    return res;
  });

  console.log(languages);

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

and the output on the console is:

```
>Promise {<pending>}
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

** That's from the debugging mode when I pause inside the promise:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9nHi.png

Answer (score 1):

You can't `try catch` a returned promise without the `await` keyword in an `async` function.

If you're returning a promise, you need to use the `.catch` method on the promise.

Also, when you're logging `languages` you're doing so before the promise resolves *because* you're not using the `await` keyword.

I'm sure the promise resolves. Instead, log `res` inside the `.then` method.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require("csv-parser");

const results = [];

function readCSV(filepath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs
      .createReadStream(filepath)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", (data) => {
        results.push(data);
      })
      .on("error", (error) => reject(results))
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve(results);
      });
  });
}


const csvFilePath = "./languages.csv";

(async () => {
  const output = await readCSV(csvFilePath);
  console.log(output)
})();
```

Comment: well, console logging doesn't seem to output everything fully.I get an array that has the number of rows I have in the .csv file, but I can't click on the variables so it seems like an empty array essentially:
>Promise {<pending>}
>(108) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},  …]
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
>[0..99]
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
>[100..107]
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Secondly, I want to use this data in another module within this project, so may you know how I could export this outside of the callback in .then?

Comment: That's not an error, that's just telling you the limitations of the console output. Rest assured, in the `.then`, you are getting back all the data. Whether you output it outside of the `.then` is irrelevant.  I refactored your code and provided it as an edit to my last post.